# How to use \floatfoot in a xltabular?

Tags: longtable, tablenotes

I have a long table, and I used the `xltabular` package. I use `\floatfoot{}` for writing notes below each table. However, when I use `\floatfoot{}` in a `xltabular` environment, the note is simply ignored. What should I do?

Many thanks in advance.

Here is the code example:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lXXXXXXXXXXc}


.... some thing ...
\caption{some caption}
\floatfoot{some notes}
\label{tab:chars_colored} 
\end{xltabular}
```

Comment: a longtable isn't a float. can't you simply use `\footnote` ? Of course `\floatfoot` is not a standard command and you have not given an example showing how it is defined so I am just guessing it is related to float evironments from the name.

Comment: You may look  in `threeparttable` . It enable to write notes below table.